# File reading in C not working using structures together with union

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm having difficulties using **char ch** instead of **char ch[2]**. The code keeps grabbing other letters or characters instead of the intended H and S. I'm trying to read a file employees.txt that has some data like this: **H 1111 Jane Doe 8.50 40.0**. H = Hourly Employee, 1111 = ID, Jane Doe = full name, 8.5 = pay rate and 40 = hours worked. The H at the beginning is to indicate the EmployeeType which I'm trying to grab using **char ch** but keeps giving grabbing different characters instead of the H and the S alone. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ID_SIZE 4
#define NAME_SIZE 15

typedef enum {Hourly, Sales} EmployeeType;

// Employee structure with union for employee types
typedef struct {
   EmployeeType type;
   char id[ID_SIZE + 1],
        first_name[NAME_SIZE + 1], last_name[NAME_SIZE + 1];
   union {
      struct { float pay_rate, hours_worked; } hourly_emp;
      struct { float commission_rate, sales_amount; } sales_emp;
   };
} Employee;

// Reads the data of an employee from a file.
Employee read_data(FILE *in_file) {
    Employee emp;
    char ch;
    fscanf(in_file, "%c %s %s %s", ch, emp.id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name);

    if(ch == 'H'){
        emp.type = Hourly;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.hourly_emp.pay_rate, &emp.hourly_emp.hours_worked);
    }
    else{
        emp.type = Sales;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.sales_emp.commission_rate, &emp.sales_emp.sales_amount);
    }

    return emp;
}

float weekly_salary(Employee emp) {
    switch(emp.type){
        case Hourly: return emp.hourly_emp.pay_rate * 40 + ((emp.hourly_emp.hours_worked - 40) * emp.hourly_emp.pay_rate * 1.5);
        case Sales: return emp.sales_emp.commission_rate * emp.sales_emp.sales_amount;
        default: return -1.0;
    }
}

// Writes the data of a student and the evaluation into file.
void write_data(FILE *out_file, Employee emp, float salary) {
    fprintf(out_file, "%s %s %s %.2f\n", emp.id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name, salary);
}

// Starts the execution of the program.
int main(void) {
    FILE *employees_file = fopen("employees.txt", "r");
    if (employees_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: File employees.txt was not found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    FILE *payroll_file = fopen("payroll.txt", "w");

    Employee employees = read_data(employees_file);

    float salary;

    while (! feof(employees_file)) {
        salary = weekly_salary(employees);
        write_data(payroll_file, employees, salary);
        employees = read_data(employees_file);
    }

    fclose(employees_file);
    fclose(payroll_file);
    printf("All employees were read and payroll was written.\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm trying to determine the TYPE of Employee so the program can properly calculate the Weekly_Salary and create and print the data of the employee in an output file (payroll.txt) with the salary instead of the hours and the pay rate.

This is the data:

> H 1111 Jane Doe 8.50 40.0
> S 2222 John Doe 0.10 1500.00
> H 3333 George Miles 7.25 45.0
> H 4444 Tamara Smith 8.25 42.5
> S 5555 Rose Watson 0.15 2000.00

Also, the following code worked for me but I know is not the most efficient way since I'm using a String to grab just a single character:

```
Employee read_data(FILE *in_file) {
    Employee emp;
    char ch[2];
    fscanf(in_file, "%s %s %s %s", ch, emp.id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name);

    if(strcmp(ch, "H") == 0){
        emp.type = Hourly;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.hourly_emp.pay_rate, &emp.hourly_emp.hours_worked);
    }
    else{
        emp.type = Sales;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.sales_emp.commission_rate, &emp.sales_emp.sales_amount);
    }

    return emp;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
1111 Jane Doe 340.00
2222 John Doe 150.00
3333 George Miles 344.38
4444 Tamara Smith 360.94
```

Sorry if this is way to much information

Comment: In `fscanf` the `ch` needs to be `&ch`. Your compiler should give you a warning for that so always pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: But I don't think even that's going to work because `"%c"` will read the newline character at the end of the first line when you try to parse the second line. Change that to be `" %c"` (leading space).

Comment: It worked. The leading space and the ampersand did the trick. Now, is there anything else you guys which to change? Something to improve the program. I may add another function that evaluates that **ch** and returns the EmployeeType. Food for thought, that way in the future that function can add more capabilities to the whole program.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kaylum which came with the answer to fix the program's issue. I was missing an ampersand before **ch** when reading the first character in the FILE, and also added a line space **" %c"** in the format specifier so it only reads the first character on each newline and no other character on that line.

```
// Reads the data of a employee from a file.
Employee read_data(FILE *in_file) {
    Employee emp;
    char ch;
    fscanf(in_file, " %c %s %s %s", &ch, emp.id, emp.first_name, emp.last_name);

    if(cd == 'H'){
        emp.type = Hourly;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.hourly_emp.pay_rate, &emp.hourly_emp.hours_worked);
    }
    else {
        emp.type = Sales;
        fscanf(in_file, "%f %f", &emp.sales_emp.commission_rate, 
              &emp.sales_emp.sales_amount);
    }

    return emp;
}
```